# Necessary and sufficient condition for $P(\xi\geq b)=1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm working on the following question and I don't see how the claim of the problem is even possible

> Let $\xi$ be a non-negative random variable.  Prove that for $b>0$, $$\lim_{t\to +\infty}\frac{1}{t}\log \mathbb Ee^{-t\xi} = -b$$ iff $P(\xi\geq b) = 1$.

Thing is, I don't see how this statement even makes sense, because there is only one possible value of that limit if it's defined, but there can potentially be many possible values of $b$ such that $P(\xi\geq b) = 1$

[Source: Fall 2015](https://dornsife.usc.edu/assets/sites/990/docs/Post_2012_papers/Probability_2012-.pdf)

Comment: You might simplify by calling the random variable $X$ and/or by putting the random variable somewhere in the expectation.

Comment: @Michael I changed the $x$ to $\xi$ since it is clearly a typo. Also, according to the source, there was a missing $\log$ in the expression, so I added that too.

Comment: Can you do any part of this?  For example if you assume $X \geq b$ then $e^{-tX} \leq e^{-tb}$ (assuming $t>0$).

Comment: @Michael I think it is safe to assume $t>0$ since we are considering the limit as $t\to+\infty$ here :)

Comment: As for the case where there is not a unique $b>0$ such that $\mathbb P(\xi\geqslant b)=1$, the claim would still be valid if the given limit failed to equal $-b$ (or even exist).

Comment: I also cant think of any cases where there would even be a unique $b>0$ since $b-\epsilon$ should also work right?

Comment: Looks like $X=1/2$ (with prob 1) is a counter-example in one direction.  Try $b=1/2$ and $b=1/4$.

Comment: You are right, the "if and only if" cannot hold. Namely, if $b>0$ satisfies the second condition, then so does $b/2$; however, the LHS of the first condition stays the same...

Comment: Good point. Considering this seems to be from a comprehensive exam, I'm surprised that such an error was made in the question...

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix the question? because the limit of the expected value seems like a highly specific expression, I'm wondering if there is just a simple typo.

Comment: I think the first fix is to change the squiggly thing to $X$.  =)  I don't see why a problem about a general random variable would not use $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fix: Let $X$ be *any* random variable such that $E[e^{-tX}]$ is finite for all $t >0$.  Prove:

1) If $b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $P[X<b]=0$ then 
$$ \limsup_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{t}\log(E[e^{-tX}]) \leq -b $$

2) If $b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $P[X<b]>0$ then 
$$ \liminf_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{t}\log(E[e^{-tX}]) > -b $$

3) Conclude that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{t}\log(E[e^{-tX}])$ exists (possibly being $\infty$) and is equal to $-b^*$, where
$$ b^* = \inf \{b \in \mathbb{R} : P[X<b]>0\} $$

4) Conclude that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{t}\log(E[e^{-tX}]) \leq -b$ if and only if $P[X\geq b] =1$.